# CORS redirect works unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, redirect, https, cors

According to CORS specification (7.1.7 - Redirect Steps (for Simple Cross-Origin Request)):

> 6. If the request URL origin is not same origin with the original URL origin, set source origin to a globally unique identifier (becomes "null" when transmitted).

I have a scenario where javascript from a.blah.com makes a CORS request (i.e. Origin request header present) by sending browser to b.blah.com, which responds with a 302 and location = c.blah.com. If I am reading the spec correctly, this should result in the request to c.blah.com containing Origin header = "null". Instead, the Origin header is not present and thus the request to c.blah.com is not considered a CORS request.

The above behavior was experienced in Chrome 54. I have not confirmed the exact request contents in other browsers, but I have checked that my particular application flow works in Chrome 54, Firefox 37, and IE 11 browsers, which implies they never see Origin header set to "null" (my services will fail requests loudly if the receive an Origin = "null").

This all worries me because while my application is working, it actually shouldn't be, and I don't want to just ignore this fact. Am I misunderstanding the spec? Are there any caveats to the spec behavior that I've missed?

All traffic is HTTPS, not returning * (wildcard) in CORS response header, setting with-credentials flags/headers as appropriate, no proxies in use, all actors on separate machines so should not be a localhost gotcha...

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly how are these HTTP requests being made?

Comment: The request to b.blah.com is a form being posted by js (not an xhr). I set up a test where the request to b.blah.com was xhr, and that did cause an Origin = "null" on the request to c.blah.com. After some digging around, it seems I need to better research the nuances of when same-origin policy is enforced.

Answer (score 2):

In my original configuration, the request to b.blah.com was a form posted by js (not xhr). After some digging around, it seems that since the request was triggered by js, that warranted an Origin header on the request to b.blah.com, but the resulting redirect to c.blah.com was handled by the browser without any script/xhr intervention, so the redirect was not decorated with an Origin header.

I set up a test where the request to b.blah.com was xhr, and that did cause an Origin = "null" on the redirect to c.blah.com.

I suppose I need to better research the nuances of when same-origin policy is enforced.

Thanks.